# How to correctly edit scalability settings/groups in Unreal Engine 4? To "overwrite" the default one's

Tags: settings, scalability, unreal-engine4, ini

So from what I gathered this can be done by editing an "ini" config file, but whatever file I edited there were no changes in testing. So whatever little information I managed to gather on that subject did little to no help with my problem.
So my question is: How can it be done exactly? What file/files exactly do I need to edit? And how are the correct edits done?
In one of the posts I read about that, someone mentioned that before stating "group names" with wanted settings, in ini file it should be stated system settings "group" i.e.:

[SystemSettings]

r.DefaultFeature.AntiAliasing=2

r.TemporalAACurrentFrameWeight=0.2

r.TemporalAASamples=32

r.TemporalAASharpness=0.8

r.Tonemapper.Sharpen=1

;or how ever you want your own settings, and then after that you put other group settings, i.e.:

[FoliageQuality@2]

foliage.DensityScale=0.60

grass.DensityScale=0.60

;or whatever else...

I would be immensely grateful for any help with my problem and lack of knowledge with said subject.

Answer (score 1):

Scroll to the bottom of this page.

https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/TestingAndOptimization/PerformanceAndProfiling/Scalability/ScalabilityReference/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).